# Spring AOP with @annotation(...) seems not to work in some cases

Tags: java, annotations, spring-aop

I am new to Spring AOP. I implemented an aspect that is working just fine on one of my methods. But when I refactor the method and pull out some of the logic (including the annotation which I use to trigger the aspect) then the aspect is not called any more. More details are provided below.

I have something similar to this:

```
@RequiresCheck
public ServiceResult<AccountDto> save(AccountDto accountDto) {
    // some logic here
    accountRepository.save(account.toAccount());
    // some logic there
    return ServiceResult.ok(accountDto);
}
```

And an aspect that looks similar to this

```
@Around("@annotation(requiresCheck)")
public Object checkFullSemRights(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    if (check()) {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    throw new Exception();
}
```

This code works just fine! When I refactor the first method to look like this:

```
public ServiceResult<AccountDto> save(AccountDto accountDto) {
    // some logic here
    return save2(accountDto.toAccount());
}

@RequiresCheck
public ServiceResult<AccountDto> save2(Account account) {
    accountRepository.save(account);
    // some logic there
    return ServiceResult.ok(account.toAccountDto());
}
```

Then the aspect is not executed anymore. I thought that the aspect should get executed for any method that has the annotation "@ResuiresCheck", but that seems not to be true. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Internal calls cannot be intercepted using Spring AOP . Please read through the reference documentation [section](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)  , info starting with _Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework_

Comment: Thank you for the hint to the documentation, I didn't catch this one. If you would write this as an answer, I could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internal calls cannot be intercepted using Spring AOP .

Relevant information from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, calls within
>   the target object are, by definition, not intercepted. For JDK
>   proxies, only public interface method calls on the proxy can be
>   intercepted. With CGLIB, public and protected method calls on the
>   proxy are intercepted (and even package-visible methods, if
>   necessary). However, common interactions through proxies should always
>   be designed through public signatures.